# How can i change the background from my animation in compsitor?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I created an animation-a turntable-and i want to change my background color .I can do this in the compositor? I know i can do this from the world tab but i used a Hdri and i cant change the color without influence the light.I can do this if i render the animation as pictures?

I am using cycles

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Evee? basically you need to render out a mask and use that in compositing to change the background. This is how you render a mask: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDNi-NNSlyY And this node helps you extract your data in the compositor: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/mask.html

Comment: And before i extract the data in compositor i have to render my animation before ?

Comment: What i should do first after creating the mask?

Comment: you can either rerender the whole animation or just the alpha mask as a seperate layer, i presume. I wanted to push you in the right direction, but havent done something like that in Blender / Cycles myself yet, thats why I only commented and didnt give an answer.

Comment: I found that i can use an alpha over node in the compositor and then i just have to render the animation .

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the background in the compositor with the environment pass and either an alpha over node or a mix node.

[image]